# Android Beginner: Trying to run my Android app on my Nexus 5

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in Android development, and I'm trying to figure out Eclipse and the development environment and how everything is set up.  I found a guide on developer.android.com, but it really isn't helping to get my test app running on my devoce.  I've connected my Nexus 5 to my PC, I've enabled USB Debugging and all that.  I have a simple app created... but when I try to run it, it only wants to run on the Virtual Device.  The guide I'm following just says "Enable USB Debugging," but that doesn't seem to do the trick.  What am I missing?  How do I run my app on my device?

Comment: have u install the proper ADB drivers? u can find them in the SDK under SDK/extras/google/usb_driver

Comment: How does one do that?  I found the files I think... there's androidwinusba64.cat (I assume that's it?).  What do I do with it?

Comment: It looks like you're asking what you are missing from "a guide". But we don't know what's in the guide, nor do we know the slightest of what you are doing (not even what OS you are using). You ask in the origional form of the question to be adviced of when it might be offtopic. Well, in its current form its not really I guess. Maybe If you'd add some more details? As it stands, you might just want to head over to androdi enthousiasts, as it is hardly a programming question as defined in the help...

Comment: in the Device manager while the phone connected do Update Driver and select the currect file according to your OS

Comment: I'm not sure which driver to update.  I'm running Win 7.  In Device Manager, I see a whole list of Universal Serial Bus controllers, but I don't see anything that resembles my device (Nexus 5).

Nanne - I'm trying to run an application on my Nexus 5 from Eclipse in Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit).  I'm not sure why my question was edited, though it says you edited it.  My guide can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

Comment: Fortunately, I got a nice downvote!  More damage to my reputation because I simply didn't know where to ask the question.

Comment: since we have no idea which devices in your Device Manager we cant help but you should see unknown device when using Debug mode.

Comment: Welp, I figured it out.  The Android device doesn't show up in my USB device list.  I've been operating under the assumption that the "driver" is the same as what gets auto-installed when you first plug a device into a computer.  So, my assumption was that I should be treating my device as a removable disk, as if it's the same as moving files back and forth to its internal drive.  The device was actually showing up in Android Devices > Nexus 5.  I went there and did update driver, then followed the directions provided by the link posted below by Andre, and now I'm able to run my app.

Comment: It would be awesome to post my solution, or at least upvote Andre for helping out, but because of StackExchanges policy about "you have to earn a reputation before you can earn a reputation" I can't do either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the **Google USB Driver**, which comes in the `Android SDK platform` see more here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-enable-usb-debugging-nexus

Comment: Thanks.  This helps understand my problem a bit.  Unfortunately, when I try to install the inf file, it says "The INF file you selected does not support this method of installation."  A quick search suggested I go through Device Manager... but, when I do that, I can't really tell which driver I should "Update."  There is a whole slew of USB devices in DM, but none of them resemble my device.

Comment: Win 7.  Actually, I figured it out.  That link really helped a lot.  I would upvote you, but I don't have enough of a "reputation (which is ridiculous imo)."  I can't even answer my own question to say what the solution was.

Comment: @Shonenknife, As you can not vote up my answer, do not worry :), the fact you have helped already done my part here in the community !